# Passing a list to a function using Timer

Tags: python, list, timer

I have this `function`:

```
def play(id1):
        print 'playing', id1
        os.system("osascript -e 'tell application \"Spotify\" to play track \"%s\"'" % (id1,))
```

Then I wrote a loop to generate a list of `track_id`s and play each correspondant song, on a sequence:

```
for i, song in enumerate(songs):     
    for track in song:
        track = song['tracks'][i]
        track_id = track['foreign_id'].replace('-WW', '')
    print "%d %-32.32s %s" % (i, song['artist_name'], song['title']) 
        play(track_id)
    time.sleep(3000)
```

but only one song (last one on the list) is playing. what is wrong?

Comment: There are a lot of different ways you could do this, and which one is best will depend on what your goal with this program is. The easiest way would be to just use `time.sleep(x)` to pause for `x` seconds.

Comment: @RobWatts actually, I would like it to sleep for the duration of each song, as I intend to have a playlist.

Comment: @jDo removed, thanks.